# OrionJS stylesheet is applying over all templates

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, meteor-packages

I am using a Meteor CMS : [OrionJS](http://orionjs.org/docs/introduction)

Package installation requires installation of one of this two packages:
Bootstrap (bootstrap:bootstrap) or Materialize (materialize:materialize). Without one of this packages, the CMS interface have no stylesheet.

But the installation of this style packages take place on every template of the project.

So, I'm looking for a solution. How to apply the style package on just a piece of the application? (The best solution, because this package load jquery everywhere)

Or how don't apply the stylesheet and his javascript on my template.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution from a community add-on packages:

https://github.com/nicolaslopezj/orion-admin-only-bootstrap